# Review after your "limit", but for no additional "points"

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

**Request:**

Allow users who have hit their "limit" on reviews to still be able to view and help with auditing, but don't award the count towards their badge progression.  This can only be applied to higher rep ceiling reviews or to certain queues if needed.

---

**Reasoning:**
I recently reached enough rep to start reviewing edits and low quality posts, and I feel like I have been opened to the flood gates of low quality stuff being posted en masse as of late.  I am finding myself quickly burning through the 20 reviews of these kinds that are pushing me to my 10+ hour "limit".  After already finding edits that were accepted that needed to be rolled back or fixed (shouldn't have been approved), I feel as if those queues are a great way for someone to find troublesome posts to fix and improve quality.

Once I have hit my limit it is hard to find these sometimes, particularly edits that shouldn't have been approved or need fixing.  Low quality posts are easier to find, since I can just look at the newest questions asked and see a slew of them flying in.

I know people edit and review a bunch to earn badges and points, which is how I started getting into reviewing.  I understand part of the limit is to allow other users the opportunity to review to count towards their badges and help out, and allowing this limits other users.  Is there some kind of balance that can be acheived where people hungry to help edit/review can help with the queues as an extra auditing set of eyes, while still allowing users who haven't reached their limit to earn towards their points/badges?

Comment: I wonder if there is a 1:1 correlation between the robo-reviewing set and badge-hunting set. If so, your suggestion is a good one. If, however, there are roboreviewers who are motivated by something else, this change could be problematic

Comment: @GeorgeCummins if there are roboreviewers who are motivated by other things, then I think the bigger review process is in bigger trouble.  If people are just rushing through reviews for one reason or another, if the ultimate goal isn't to reach the proper outcome (improve quality of SO) then we have bigger fish to fry.  I am trying to add another safety net where non-robo reviewers can easily help catch things that slip through the robo reviewed net.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins There's at least some divergence; I'm a badge-hunter but get thoroughly annoyed at bad queue decisions, and I'm trying to come up with a way to smack robo-reviewers (especially on Suggested Edits) more reliably than the current audit system does.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a double edged sword.  While it helps you attempt to review more items properly, it also allows people who aren't reviewing properly to review more posts too.  While there will be some people who are interested in *nothing* but the badge and won't continue beyond what counts towards it, there will still be *plenty* of people reviewing that aren't doing a good job, and will continue to review lots and lots of posts.

Another reason for having a limit is to prevent users from burning out; when you start reviewing lots and lots of content in a short period of time it's draining; people review so much over a few days that they stop reviewing from then on, instead of the more sustainable handful of reviews each day.

Comment: Is there some middle ground where I can view recent approved edits in a list, and just quickly scan through them to see if I find any that jump out and require fixing?  Sometimes I have a lot of free time...

Comment: @Walls There is, but it requires 10k reputation to access.

Comment: @Walls Of course, [there are pleanty of ways of reviewing content without using a review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155573/186381).  There's plenty of crap out there to deal with, and lots of ways of finding it.