# I want to review more

Tags: feature-request

There are 15 edits in the queue. There is a orange thing at the top. **I want to review!**

…but I finished 20 reviews today. i can haz moar reviewz?

- Allow more reviews with more reputation?
- Allow more reviews when audits are passed?
- Allow more reviews after steward?
- Allow more reviews in general?

Comment: 4) Allow for transferring review rights ;-) (Sorry, I'm a slacker, I don't use my review rights. U can haz mine.)

Comment: Have you finished your 40 CVQ reviews?

Comment: @OGHaza I do those in the afternoon. I'm in the mood for edits in the morning.

Comment: @bjb568 my best recommendation is to get a life. j/k! ***Or am I???*** `:D <3 <3 <3 :P`

Comment: @Cupcake but not all of us can get a life :( I tried a few cheats but none worked :(

Comment: Shrink, I want to review. I mean, I wanna, I wanna review. Review. I wanna, I wanna see, I wanna see blood and gore and guts and veins in my teeth. Eat dead burnt bodies. I mean review, Review, REVIEW, REVIEW.

Comment: @Shog9 That got real dark real fast

Comment: Very innovative request. I was looking for a person like you to gift all my reviews to...:)

Comment: Why did Community delete this? If every unpopular feature-request gets deleted, then people will just ask them over and over and over again.

Comment: @user000001 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238858/237813

Comment: more_reviews_after_steward++  That's a solid idea.

Comment: Users who get review banned should have the ban duration's worth of reviews forfeited and distributed to random reviewers with good track records.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254175/review-after-your-limit-but-for-no-additional-points

Answer (score 2):

The Edit Review queue already empties quickly. I rarely see more than a dozen or so items queuing up. Based on this, I don't see a reason to increase the limit.

I actually think it's preferable to distribute the review tasks across more users as long as they get handled. Raising the limits would concentrate them on fewer users. Which means that fewer users get a chance to participate in site moderation. Also, if you have bad reviewers, they will be able to do more damage.

The only queue that does not get processed sufficiently fast is the Close queue. The limit is already 40 reviews/day there, because the queue has more than 1000 items. If any limit is considered for being raised, I think it should be that one. Even though I'm slightly concerned that people would get tired of it pretty quickly if they spend too much time on reviews, and would end up stopping completely. It might still be better to keep people reviewing in the long run, and maintaining a reasonable rate limit reduces the risk of burning out. And again, the infamous "robo-reviewers" who do a lot of reviews without much thought would be the most likely to take advantage of a higher limit.

Comment: Why do you think distributing reviews to more users will decrease robo reviewing?

Comment: @bjb568 Rate limiting has the highest effect on people who perform tasks at a high rate. Which are the people who review without really reading the posts. Of course this is just what I predict would happen, I do not have data to back it up. If you increase the limits, available review items will be even more scarce, and the people who review the fastest will pick up a higher percentage.

Comment: But if more people have access to it, the drive-by reviewers who just want a badge would have an easier time. Rate limiting also affects those who devote a lot of time to reviewing.